# Android: Fetch GPS data from Service when Screen is Off

Tags: android, service, background, gps, wakelock

I need to fetch gps data within a service when the screen is off. It always pauses when the screen is off. Inside the service I use postDelayed to wait 3 minutes and then fetch the gps data.
Do I need to acquire a wakeLock? But then how would I do this? The data should be fetched about every 3 minutes, possibly for several hours in the background. I can't have a wakeLock all the time, or can I?
How would you do this?

Comment: Use a wakelock. You can keep it for hours if you need to. There is plenty of documentation. If you get stuck, ask a more specific question.